# Unable to add some values while converting Excel to VCF using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos, vcf-vcard

I am trying to convert my excel file to a VCF.But I am not be able to add Fax and Address in VCF format. Rest of the values I can convert but Unable to add fax and Address in VCF. My code is given below:

```
Sub excelTovcf()
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim FirstName As String
    Dim LastName As String
    Dim FullName As String
    Dim EmailAddress As String
    Dim PhoneHome As String
    Dim PhoneWork As String
    Dim Organization As String
    Dim JobTitle As String

    iRow = 7
    ' set a unique integer for the new
    ' text file
    FileNum = FreeFile
    ' Save this vcf file on desktop
    OutFilePath = VBA.Environ$("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\MyContacts.VCF"
    Open OutFilePath For Output As FileNum

    With Sheets("contacts")
    While VBA.Trim(.Cells(iRow, 1)) <> ""
        FirstName = VBA.Trim(.Cells(iRow, 1))
        LastName = VBA.Trim(.Cells(iRow, 2))
        FullName = VBA.Trim(.Cells(iRow, 3))
        EmailAddress = VBA.Trim(.Cells(iRow, 4))
        PhoneHome = VBA.Trim(.Cells(iRow, 5))
        PhoneWork = VBA.Trim(.Cells(iRow, 6))
        Organization = VBA.Trim(.Cells(iRow, 7))
        JobTitle = VBA.Trim(.Cells(iRow, 8))
        Fax = VBA.Trim(.Cells(iRow, 9))
        Address = VBA.Trim(.Cells(iRow, 15))



    ' Start printing the data in above specified
    ' format of VCF file format
        Print #FileNum, "BEGIN:VCARD"
        Print #FileNum, "VERSION:3.0"
        Print #FileNum, "N:" & FirstName & ";" & LastName & ";;;"
        Print #FileNum, "FN:" & FullName
        Print #FileNum, "ORG:" & Organization
        Print #FileNum, "TITLE:" & JobTitle
        Print #FileNum, "TEL;TYPE=HOME,VOICE:" & PhoneWork
        Print #FileNum, "TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:" & PhoneHome
        Print #FileNum, "TEL,TYPE=WORK,FAX:" & Fax
        Print #FileNum, "EMAIL:" & EmailAddress
        Print #FileNum, "END:VCARD"
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Wend
 End With
    'Close The File
    MsgBox "Total " & iRow - 7 & " Contacts are exported to VCF File. It is saved on your Desktop"
    Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

Need help how can I add fax and Address in VCF from my excel file.
I am a beginner so unable to resolve this issue.

Comment: I suspect your `FAX` line isn't being added due to using a comma in `TEL,TYPE=WORK,FAX:` instead of a semi-colon as used in your other lines - e.g. `TEL;TYPE=WORK,FAX:`

Comment: @CLR : Thanks..It works ,now how to add address??

Comment: See my answer below -

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, I think the following Print statements would work -

```
Print #FileNum, "BEGIN:VCARD"
Print #FileNum, "VERSION:3.0"
Print #FileNum, "N:" & FirstName & ";" & LastName & ";;;"
Print #FileNum, "FN:" & FullName
Print #FileNum, "ORG:" & Organization
Print #FileNum, "TITLE:" & JobTitle
Print #FileNum, "TEL;TYPE=HOME,VOICE:" & PhoneWork
Print #FileNum, "TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:" & PhoneHome
Print #FileNum, "TEL;TYPE=WORK,FAX:" & Fax
Print #FileNum, "EMAIL:" & EmailAddress
Print #FileNum, "ADR;TYPE=HOME:" & Address
Print #FileNum, "END:VCARD"
iRow = iRow + 1
```

Keep in mind, the `Address` string should look something like:

`LINE1;LINE2;LINE3;LINE4;LINE5;ZIP/POSTCODE;COUNTRY`

So you may have to `Replace` in-cell return codes with semi-colons if the address is in once cell.